# How can expanding trigonometric function retain an expression?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

I want to expand this trigonometric function

```
Sin[π/4 + α - β]
```

such that $\alpha - \beta$ is treated as "one" expression, resulting in

```
Sqrt[2]/2 Cos[α - β] + Sqrt[2]/2 Sin[α - β]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temporary replace `α - β` with some other dummy symbol, for example `αβ`, then replace back after [`TrigExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigExpand.html).

```
(Sin[π/4 + α - β] /. α - β -> αβ // TrigExpand) /. αβ -> α - β

(* Cos[α - β]/Sqrt[2] + Sin[α - β]/Sqrt[2] *)
```

Comment: Or `Sin[π/4 + α - β] // TrigExpand // Simplify`

Answer (score 3):

This is such a common problem, that it is worth knowing more than one way of doing it.  I always try to make the LHS of replacement rules as simple as possible, and to make the replacement obviously correct.

```
Sin[Pi/4 + a - b] /. a -> HoldForm[a - b] + b // TrigExpand
(*Cos[HoldForm[a - b]]/Sqrt[2] + Sin[HoldForm[a - b]]/Sqrt[2]*)
```

The `HoldForm` is typically hidden, and can be eliminated with `ReleaseHold` when you no longer need the terms to be treated as a unit.