Why is it that defining the range of angles makes it impossible to find a solution Sin[a + b]==-((2 Sqrt[2])/3)?

Given that α is an angle in the first quadrant and β is an angle in the third quadrant, and tan α + tan β = 4, tan α tan β = √2 + 1, then sin(α + β) = __________.

Without limiting the range of angles a and b, multiple solutions Sin[a + b] can be found.
Clear["`*"]
Solve[{Tan[a] + Tan[b] == 4, Tan[a] Tan[b] == Sqrt[2] + 1, 
   sin == Sin[a + b]}] // Simplify



Why is it that defining the range of angles a and b ( 2 k Pi < a < 2 k Pi + Pi/2,  2 k Pi + Pi < b < 2 k Pi + 3 Pi/2, k \[Element] Integers) makes it impossible use FullSimplify to find a solution that Sin[a + b]==-((2 Sqrt[2])/3)?

Clear["`*"];
sol = Solve[{Tan[a] + Tan[b] == 4, Tan[a] Tan[b] == Sqrt[2] + 1, 
    Sin[a + b] == sin, 2 k Pi < a < 2 k Pi + Pi/2, 
    2 k Pi + Pi < b < 2 k Pi + 3 Pi/2, k \[Element] Integers}, {a, b, 
    sin}, Reals] // FullSimplify


I don't even see your effort in asking a clear question. (-1)

Solve[{Tan[a] + Tan[b] == 4, Tan[a] Tan[b] == Sqrt[2] + 1,    Sin[a + b] == sin, 2 k Pi < a < 2 k Pi + Pi/2,    2 k Pi + Pi < b < 2 k Pi + 3 Pi/2, k \[Element] Integers}, {a, b,    sin}, Reals] works on my machine, version "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"

@JieZhu This code can run, but adding the simplification does not yield the desired result.

Why do you still refuse to learn anything after asking 305 undeleted questions?
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A68574+TrigExpand
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284620/1871
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286618/1871
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/301256/1871
sin /. Solve[{sin == Sin[a + b], Tan[a] + Tan[b] == 4, Tan[a] Tan[b] == Sqrt[2] + 1, 
     2 k Pi < a < 2 k Pi + Pi/2, 2 k Pi + Pi < b < 2 k Pi + 3 Pi/2, 
     k ∈ Integers}, {a, b, sin}] // TrigExpand // FullSimplify


